# How to dynamically add columns in Dash DataTable based on selected dropdown values

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to dynamically add columns in a DataTable based on selected dropdown values using Dash. 
My table is created also dynamically based on two dropdowns (I have a callback that returns the whole DataTable definition).

I tried the example that is in [Adding or removing columns](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/editable) section, but it works only when you try to add columns using a button.

This is my code for adding the columns:

```py
@app.callback(
[Output(‘main_table’, ‘columns’)],
[Input(‘second_dropdown’, ‘value’)],
[State(‘main_data’, ‘data’), State(‘main_table’, ‘columns’)]
)
def add_columns(values, data, existing_columns):
if existing_columns is None:
return None
for value in values:
if value not in existing_columns:
existing_columns.append({
‘id’: value,
‘name’: value
})
print(existing_columns)
return existing_columns
```

The *'main_data'* is stored in a json file which contains the data that should be displayed when the values in the second dropdown are changed. 
As result I expect to have a table which columns are as the number of selected dropdown values.

I'm new to Dash so I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone also has the same problem, here is the solution (many thanks to [Marc-Andre](https://community.plot.ly/t/dynamically-add-columns-in-datatable-based-on-selected-dropdown-values/27947/2)):

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

from dash_table import DataTable, FormatTemplate
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[{
            'label': 'label: ' + id,
            'value': id
        } for id in ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
    ),
    DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[{
            'name': x,
            'id': x,
            'selectable': True
        } for x in ['a']],
        column_selectable="single",
        data=[{
            'a': 'a' + str(x),
            'b': 'b' + str(x),
            'c': 'c' + str(x),
            'd': 'd' + str(x),
            'e': 'e' + str(x),
            'f': 'f' + str(x)
        } for x in range(0,100)]
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'columns'),
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')],
    [State('table', 'columns')]
)
def update_columns(value, columns):
    if value is None or columns is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    inColumns = any(c.get('id') == value for c in columns)

    if inColumns == True:
        raise PreventUpdate

    columns.append({
        'label': 'label: ' + value,
        'id': value
    })
    return columns

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```